# Why there is no Events button in the Properties window for HTML button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I want it to generate a simple `onclick` JavaScript event for an HTML button. I select the button in the Designer, go to properties, but there is no lightning bolt button for events. How to fix this?

Comment: The events (lightning thingies) are only for Asp.Net (C#) events (not for DOM events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event doesn't exist because the HtmlButton Class is just a wrapper so the render can create a  HTML output.

The base ASP.NET equivalent (with events) would be a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.

Now, all System.Web.UI.HtmlControls accept the AddAttribute method, which would allow you to programatically specify the control's behavior. For example, let's say you have this code on your HTML page:

```
<input type='Button' ID='btn1'>
```

And you want to add a javascript event. First, make it accessible by the server-side code:

```
<input type='Button' ID='btn1' runat='server'>
```

Then, on the codebehind, add the content:

```
this.btn1.AddAttribute("onclick", "doSomething();");
```

There you go. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery

```
$("#btnID").click(function() {
 ///your actions
});
```

Read more on http://api.jquery.com/click/